# Assert, modify state, assert again?

Tags: mocha.js

How can I perform some tests (`it()` calls) about an object under test, then call a `method()` on it, and then perform some more tests on the object's state modified by `method()`?

The problem is that a call to `it()` schedules the actual assertion to be performed much later, and as a result of this ALL the tests will actually run after the call to `method()`, including those that I want to run before that call. How to overcome this?

Comment: Assert, modify state, and assert again is absolutely trivial to do. Where the problem lies, and how to fix it cannot be determined accurately until you provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Louis Is that an automated response? Did you read my question? It is deliberately general because the problem is general. The solution is trivial once you realize that `it()` callbacks are not limited to asserting, but figuring this out is nontrivial since the vast majority of introductory examples only use arrow functions with a single assertion in the body, leaving a strong impression that modifying state in `it()` callbacks is some dreaded testing antipattern.